# Reference project not match the real one

Tags: c#, reference

I have two project in different solutions,
and in one of them (let call it A) there is a refernce to the other one (let call it B).

it was good, untill I decide I need another Ctor in one of the classes in B.

But in A I can't use this Ctor

I tried close and open the visual studio,
shut down the computer,
wait few hours
delete and readd the refernce in A to B.

but I still can't use this Ctor...

what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you add the reference?

Comment: right click - > add refernce - > browes -> find the project folder - > bin - > choose the dll file named as the project

Comment: Did you *build* the first solution? Did you build the correct variation of it? DEBUG or RELEASE, depending on which reference you added?

Comment: Is your constructor for the class in B public?

Comment: Yes, I build them both, and it is public.
it was good at the beginning, but I just can't edit it

Comment: is the class public?

Comment: yes, it's public.
I already used ather methids in this class, except the new Ctor

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot have both of the projects in the same solution?

Comment: it posible, yes,
but I prefered that the project wount be in the same solution, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

rebuild B.

(Build - > build solution)